# Cyclic dependency when there are multiple DataSource defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to declare two DataSource beans and use one of them dynamically using AbstractRoutingDataSource, which is declared as @Primary bean. Surprisingly, I was not able to run my application because of cyclic dependency:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration
┌─────┐
|  dataSource defined in <myclass>
↑     ↓
|  readOnlyDataSource defined in <myclass>
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker
└─────┘
```

It is cause because of this implementation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("firstDS") DataSource firstDS,
                          @Qualifier("secondDS") DataSource secondDS) {
        MyRoutingDataSource ds = new MyRoutingDataSource();
        ds.setCurrentDS(firstDS);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean("firstDS")
    public DataSource firstDS(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean("secondDS")
    public DataSource secondDs(DataSourceProperties properties) {
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    }

    class MyRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
        private DataSource currentDS;

        public void setCurrentDS(DataSource currentDS) {
            this.currentDS = currentDS;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
            return currentDS;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I don't want to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration - it provides some additional functionally that I want to use in my project (e.g. DataSourceInitializer).

Could you please explain to me why it does not work? I feel that this error message is misleading. There is no cyclic dependency between HibernateJpaConfiguration and DataSourceInitializerInvoker. Both of them uses DataSource which primary definition I provide.

There is full project with that issue: https://github.com/kozub/spring-dependency-management-bug

Comment: Your `MyRoutingDataSource` nor its confiig makes sense. Why is the lookup key the actual datasource, you should have a map of `DataSource`s and a way to determine the key to use to do a lookup.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem you have, with the difference that I am not using DataSourceAutoConfiguration.

I'm not a Spring expert, so I can't tell you the root cause. But I was able to get my code to work by going from something like this, which is similar to what you posted:

```
@Bean
@Primary
DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("firstDS") DataSource firstDS,
                      @Qualifier("secondDS") DataSource secondDS) {
    MyRoutingDataSource ds = new MyRoutingDataSource();
    ds.setFirstDS(firstDS);
    ds.setSecondDs(secondDS);
    return ds;
}

@Bean("firstDS")
    public DataSource firstDS() {
    return /*create first DS*/
}

@Bean("secondDS")
    public DataSource secondDs(DataSourceProperties properties) {
    return /*create second DS*/
}
```

To this:

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource() {
    DataSource first = /*create first DS*/
    DataSource second = /*create second DS*/

    MyRoutingDataSource ds = new MyRoutingDataSource();
    ds.setFirstDS(first);
    ds.setSecondDs(second);
    return ds;
}
```

As you can see, I was able to solve the problem by only having one Spring bean of type DataSource. I created the two "first" and "second" DataSources inside the method which creates the routing datasource so that they don't have to be Spring beans. Having only one bean of type DataSource got rid of my circular dependency error.

This solved my problem, but you also want to use DataSourceAutoConfiguration.

I think you may be able to achieve that with something like this:

```
@Bean
DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("firstDSproperties") DataSourceProperties firstDSprops,
                      @Qualifier("secondDSproperties") DataSourceProperties secondDSprops) {
    DataSource first = firstDSprops.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
    DataSource second = secondDSprops.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();

    MyRoutingDataSource ds = new MyRoutingDataSource();
    ds.setCurrentDS(firstDS);
    return ds;
}

@Bean("firstDSproperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.first")
public DataSourceProperties firstDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean("secondDSproperties")
@ConfigurationProperties("datasource.second")
public DataSourceProperties secondDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}
```

What this code does is to make two beans of type DataSourceProperties rather than type DataSource. With DataSourceProperties beans you can still let Spring autowire your config without (hopefully) having the cyclical dependency problem caused by having multiple beans of type DataSource depending on each other.

I haven't tested doing this with DataSourceProperties since I am not using DataSourceAutoConfiguration in my code. But based on your code I think it might work.

Comment: That's what I needed! Just put @Primary annotation for dataSource() method and firstDataSourceProperties(). Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

There is slight a mistake here. Let me explain you with foo and bar DB example along with git repo reference.

Here is how your `application.properties` look like

```
# Oracle DB - "foo"
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//db-server-foo:1521/FOO
spring.datasource.username=fooadmin
spring.datasource.password=foo123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
# PostgreSQL DB - "bar"
bar.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db-server-bar:5432/bar
bar.datasource.username=baradmin
bar.datasource.password=bar123
bar.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Set the SQL Dialect to “default” in your application.properties to let Spring autodetect the different SQL Dialects of each datasource

```
spring.jpa.database=default
```

Package should look something like

```
src/main/java
- com.foobar
  - foo
    - domain
    - repo
  - bar
    - domain
    - repo
```

Here is the main part. Configuration classes

**Foo Configuration class (Oracle)**

```
package com.foobar;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.foo.repo" }
)
public class FooDbConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("com.foobar.foo.domain")
      .persistenceUnit("foo")
      .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
    entityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

**Bar Configuration class (postgres)**

```
package com.foobar;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.bar.repo" }
)
public class BarDbConfig {

  @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  barEntityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return
      builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("com.foobar.bar.domain")
        .persistenceUnit("bar")
        .build();
  }
  @Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
    @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory
    barEntityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Your repositories would look something like

```
package com.foobar.bar.repo;

@Repository
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Long> {

  Bar findById(Long id); 

}


package com.foobar.foo.repo;

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

  Foo findById(Long id); 

}
```

And you are done here.

You can refer code on github [here](https://github.com/jahe/spring-boot-multiple-datasources)